# Trying to get pseudorange data out of NS-RAW GPS

Tags: programming, sensors, gps

I have an NS-RAW CPGPS and I am trying to get GPS Data using an arduino. Do I just use the serial to get the data out of it and just convert and extract the data to what I need?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: so i looked at the document for the data, how would you convert it? http://navspark.mybigcommerce.com/content/AN0030_1.4.35.pdf